# TortoiseHg (Windows) does not see file change

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I'm tearing my hair out here...

I've told TortoiseHg to create a repo of a directory that contains a mix of text files (mostly XML) and binary files.

I've done an initial commit, adding all files and ignoring `.hgignore`. Done.

Then I edited one of the XML files and saved.

The file indeed changed; I can see that the Initial Commit version has not the added line, while the version on the disk *has* the added line.

But for unknown reasons, Hg Workbench won't show the changed file!

I've tried pressing the 'refresh' buttons, all to no avail.

What is going on here? Is there a setting I've overlooked that caused TortoiseHg to ignore all files?

FYI, the `.hgignore` file only contains the following:

```
syntax: glob
.hgignore
```

I'm using TortoiseHg **v3.0.1**.

Total folder size is 280,240,487 bytes (lots of binary resources).

Thanks for any help!

---

***EDIT:*** I still don't know what had gone wrong... but I *accidentally* fixed it:

1. I opened the XML file again, and serendipitously saw that I actually made a typo.
2. I fixed the typo, and re-saved the file.
3. All of a sudden, Hg Workshop saw the change!
4. Commit before Hg Workshop changed its mind.

Thanks for trying to help me... at the moment, I'm content that the 'invisible change' is fixed.

(Although I'm still wondering what had caused it in the first place.)

Comment: Once a file has been added to the repo, it does not matter if it is ignored, it will be tracked nonetheless.

Comment: Try doing `hg status`. Do you see your modified file with a `M` in front?

Comment: @Vince unfortunately, I can't test that. I had opened the XML file again, saw that my edit had a typo, so I corrected the typo and saved and... lo and behold! Now Hg Workshop sees the change! Strange...

Comment: Edited my original question to ensure no one try to 'fix' the (possibly) non-repro problem.

Comment: Same is happening to me. TortoiseHg 4.7.0, file in question is committed to two branches (of the same name) and does not appear in _any_ diff. (Diff to local, diff to parent or diff between two nodes). However other files in the same diff sets _are_ appearing. This is actually quite serious.... how can you trust your SCM if it is not showing (or detecting) diffs?  I am going to find someone to report this to.  

Update: Command line diff ( diff -r xxxx) _DOES_ show the diffs, so this is a TortoiseHg and not an Hg issue.

Comment: Same issue. Repeatable. If I manually edit the file, it recognizes the other changes. If I rerun my program to create the file, it can't recognize it anymore. I thought maybe the date modified, but editing that doesn't fix it.